# (Org-Beamer Exporter) I would like to have a LaTeX snippet inbetween frames

Tags: org-mode, latex, beamer

I would like to change the beamer presentation background. To that end, I have to issue the following command between two frames (that is, outside any frame)

```latex
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{../Apresetacoes/Apres1/img/5.png}}
```

As frames are continuous in orgmode - either content are in the last or the next header - , I'm unable to have this piece of code in between frames.

```
*** Quadrado  rotativo
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_COL: 1
# :BEAMER_ENV: block
:END:

Something
  
#+beamer: \framebreak
#+beamer: \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{../Apresetacoes/Apres1/img/5.png}}

*** 
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_opt: standout
:END:

\begin{modern-quote-env}
\begin{modern-quote}
\color{red} \textbf{Perguntas?} \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}
\end{modern-quote}
\end{modern-quote-env}
```

Gives:

```latex
\begin{frame}[label={sec:orgc82c151}]{Quadrado  rotativo}
  something

  \framebreak %% Trying to end the frame! (Not working)
  \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{../Apresetacoes/Apres1/img/5.png}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label={sec:org008ba0c},standout]{}
  \begin{modern-quote-env}
    \begin{modern-quote}
      \color{red} \textbf{Perguntas?} \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}
    \end{modern-quote}
  \end{modern-quote-env}
\end{frame}
```

But, I want to achieve this export:

```latex
\begin{frame}[label={sec:orgc82c151}]{Quadrado  rotativo}
  something
\end{frame}

  \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{../Apresetacoes/Apres1/img/5.png}}

\begin{frame}[label={sec:org008ba0c},standout]{}
  \begin{modern-quote-env}
    \begin{modern-quote}
      \color{red} \textbf{Perguntas?} \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}
    \end{modern-quote}
  \end{modern-quote-env}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I don't know of a clean way to do this, but if worse comes to worst, you can use a [filter](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html#Advanced-Export-Configuration) to make arbitrary transformations on the "final" output of the exporter - e.g. you can search for the appropriate place and insert the snippet you want there. See also the exporter [developer documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-export-reference.html) on [Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg), the Org mode wiki.

Comment: For this I use a "fake" headline, at the same level of the frame headlines with the :ignore: tag and insert the content under this headline. The headline is not considered bu the content is. If this seems acceptable for you, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @Lgen Please, post a MWE as example; like the properties explicitly in a orgmode setup. That's acceptable to me, as far as the background of the following beamer-exported frame changes (that's acceptable to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I use a "fake" headline at the chosen level with the :ignore: tag, and insert the content under this headline. The headline is not considered, but the content is.

A working example (with a fake headline at the first level) :

```
#+OPTIONS:   H:2 toc:nil 
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer

* First part
** Slide 1
Something

* Fake headline :ignore:
#+beamer: \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[]{./Images/background.png}}

* Second part 
** Slide 2
Something else
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.